# How can I convert a subset of properties to an array of key-value pairs?

Tags: json, ecmascript-6, lodash

Imagine that I have the following object:

```
"MyObject": {
  "Foo": "b",
  "Bar": "d",
  "NewEngland": "12",
  "GreenBay": "12",
  "NewYork": "10",
  "Seattle": "3"
}
```

How can I convert this to:

```
[{
  name: 'New England', value: 12
}, {
  name: 'Green Bay', value: 12
}, {
  name: 'New York', value: 10
}, {
  name: 'Seattle', value: 3
}]
```

?

Notice that I dropped the `Foo` and `Bar` properties.

Ideally, I'd like to use either ES6 or lodash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

`_(MyObject).omit(['Foo', 'Bar']).map((value, name) => ({ name, value })).value()`

You'd be using lodash chaining, first with omit to take out the key-value pairs in the object whose keys are in that array, then you'd be using map to create an object `{ name: 'GreenBay', value: '12' }` from each key-value pair.

Answer (score 1):

One ES6 solution would be to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
let object = {
  "Foo": "b",
  "Bar": "d",
  "NewEngland": "12",
  "GreenBay": "12",
  "NewYork": "10",
  "Seattle": "3"
}

let keys = new Set(Object.keys(object))

keys.delete('Foo')
keys.delete('Bar')

let result = [...keys].map(k => ({name: k, value: object[k]}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'm puzzled by what the purpose of using the set here is.

Comment: If you have a list of `n` properties to omit, a `Set` allows you to do so in linear time instead of quadratic.